# How to get the html header values like h1 using html parser dom?

Tags: php

how to get the header value like h1 or h2 which lies inside a div having some class name using simple html parser dom?
ex: - `<html>
            <body>
              <div class="somename">
                <h1>MyText</h1>
              </div>
             </body>
            </html>`

Comment: Have you considered http://php.net/domxpath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602618/parse-html-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xPath](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to locate h1 and then remove them by looping like this:

```php
$doc = ...; // your DOM document
$xPath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("*[@class='somename']/h1");
if( !is_null( $elements)){
    foreach ($elements as $element){
        echo $element->nodeValue;
        $element->parentNode->removeChild($element); //you may also delete elements
    }
}
```

NOTE: *I've written the code out of my head, please check documentation and examples.*

Answer (score 1):

See the [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html> <body> <div class="somename"> <h1>MyText</h1> </div> </body> </html>');
$els = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach ($els as $el) {
    echo $el->nodeValue;
}
```